# C++ Regarding .h and .cpp - Multiple definition of

Tags: c++

I face a error of "multiple definition of "
I got 3 files, namely currency.h, currency.cpp,main.cpp

At currencyConverter.h under currencyConverter class 
I did

```
using namespace std;

class currencyConverter
{

string result;
stringstream ss;
size_t found,found2;

public:
   void getInbetween(string,string);

};

#endif  /* CURRENCYCONVERTER_H */
```

Then at currencyConverter.cpp I did

```
#include "currencyConverter.h"
void currencyConverter::getInbetween(string selection,string str2,string str3,string sdata)
{

buffer[result.length()] = '\0';     //insert '\0'

char * pch;
 pch = strtok (buffer," ");

}

void currencyConverter::webparser(const string siteurl,const string filename)
{
    ss << "lynx -dump '" << siteurl << "' > " << filename;
}

string currencyConverter::userOption()
{
    //some code    
    return selection;
}
```

at main2.cpp

```
#include<iostream>


#include"currencyConverter.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    currencyConverter c;
    string exitstr;


    if(selection!="6")
    {

    c.webparser(parsePage,"file.txt");    
    //now perform searchstring
    c.searchString(selection,"file.txt");
    }


    }while (1);

return 0;
}
```

This is my make file

```
# ExampleTests Project

SRCS = main2.cpp

HDRS = 

PROJ = main

CC = g++

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

APP = $(PROJ).exe

CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -I/opt/local/include

ifeq (,$(findstring CYGWIN,$(shell uname)))

LIBS = -lcppunit -ldl



all: $(APP)



$(APP): $(OBJS)

    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(APP) $(LIBS)




clean:

    rm -f *.o $(APP)
```

But i receive this error on compiler

How to get this fix.. I did not use it twice. I pasted part of my currencyConverter.cpp with the function webparser, is there a error in the way i call my function at main2.cpp ?

```
rm -f *.o main.exe

CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 86ms)
g++    -c -o main2.o main2.cpp
```

td::char_traits, std::allocator >)':
    currencyConverter.cpp:(.text+0xcec): multiple definition of `currencyConverter::webparser(std::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator >)'
    main2.o:main2.cpp:(.text+0xcec): first defined here
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [main.exe] Error 1

Comment: How do i fix this error?

Comment: Ask *"How do i fix this error?"* in the question itself, not in the comment.

Comment: Are you certain you did not cut and paste the same function name twice?

Comment: can you show your compiler call?

Comment: Added in more chunks of code.

Comment: You did not use `#include "currencyConverter.cpp"` in your `main.cpp`, did you?..

Comment: You didn't show the  main.cpp; according to the *linker* output (your compiler calls seems to run without error) it's also defined in main.cpp

Comment: I added my main2.cpp and the webparser of my currencyConverter.cpp

Comment: @user1548465 Ah, you did include `currencyConverter.cpp` instead of `currencyConverter.h`! [I knew it!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699899/c-regarding-h-and-cpp-multiple-definition-of#comment15516572_11699899)

Comment: You need to link the objects. Compile then link.

Comment: -1 For Removing the question & for doing a lot of stuff you obviously don't even know what it means. If I had to guess you just copied the code. EDIT: Question is back.

Comment: rolled-back to include the shame code.

Comment: @Layne - don't be so harsh, we were all beginners at one point and were "doing a lot of stuff we obviously didn't even know what it meant". Experience comes from bad decisions, bad decision come from bad judgment, bad judgment comes from lack of experience...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a header file, not a `cpp`:

```
#include"currencyConverter.cpp"
```

should be

```
#include"currencyConverter.h"
```

in your `main2.cpp`

Comment: But without include the cpp file, how do i call the function of currencyConverter.cpp

Comment: You include the `.h` file where the `declaration` of the functions live - this will tell compiler how to properly make the calls. You define your `interface` (name of functions, their arguments, return values) in a header `.h` file that you include into any source `.cpp` file that needs to call those functions and you *define* the `implementation` of those functions in you `.cpp` file that you build into an object `.o` file and then *link* into the final executable